# how to rewrite OOP method for tkinter lambda For-loop button?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tkinter-button

I saw some similar issue is solved by Object-oriented programming, but i am weak to use OOP and will get errors: **missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**

my code rewrite in OOP:

```
import pyperclip as pycopy
import tkinter as tk

tk_win = tk.Tk()
tk_listbox = tk.Listbox(tk_win)
tk_text = tk.Text(tk_win)

list_text = ["a", "b" ,"c"]

class COPY():

    def __init__(self, copied_text): 
        self.copied_text = copied_text


    def btn_copy_function(self):  #action for clicking button
        pycopy.copy(self.copied_text) 
        button_copy['text'] = "copied"


    def create_button(self):  #create button and data binding
        for el in list_text:
            self.copied_text = el
            button_copy = tk.Button(tk_win, text = "tick to copy", 
            command = lambda copied_text:copied_text :  COPY.btn_copy_function(self))
            tk_text.window_create(tk.INSERT, window = button_copy)
            tk_text.insert(tk.INSERT, "\n")


COPY.create_button()

tk.mainloop()
```

Or is it possible not using OOP to sovle it?

Comment: Please look at some OOP tutorials. Your approach is flawed.Also `COPY.btn_copy_function(self)` is equivalent to `self.btn_copy_function()` in this case. And you need to first instantiate `COPY` (`copy = COPY(...)`) and then call `copy.create_button()`.

Comment: FYI: If you want to use `COPY.create_button()` like this, you need to make `create_button` a [@staticmethod](https://pythonbasics.org/static-method/)